# Why cant I get the object I want

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, compare, instance

Hey so here is my problem.
I am using UTS Pro which is working fine so far.
UTS is spawning some cars(prefabs) for me and they will drive a given path.
I added deactivated script to one of the prefabs and wrote some code where is will change to active when the car hits a collider.

```
if(playerTriggered == true && playerCounter<1 && gameobj.tag == "Car")
        {
            projections = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Projection");
            foreach(GameObject projection in projections)
            {
                if(projection.GetComponentInParent<Rigidbody>().GetInstanceID() == gameobj.GetComponentInParent<Rigidbody>().GetInstanceID())
                {
                    walkPath = projection.GetComponentInParent<WalkPath>();
                    projection.GetComponentInParent<Idle>().enabled = true;
                    walkPath.setChangeCarPath(gameobj.gameObject);
                } 

            }

            playerCounter++;
        }
```

This is working fine for me.
When I press play and the car hits the collider I can see that the script is activated.
In another class I tried running this code

```
if (car.gameObject.GetComponent<Idle>().enabled == true)
        {
            Debug.Log("UM - IF");
            return points2[0, index];
        }
        else
        {
            return points[0, index];
        }
```

The thing I dont understand is that the if statement is always false.
Even though the car in the scene has an enabled script.
I also tried comparing the instance-ids of ther passed gameobject with the car object.
They also have different Ids.

Hope someone can help me and explain the problem.

Comment: while im not sure what uts pro is (im terrible with names) there isnt a [mcve] here, but, its hard to be sure what the issue is, the last batch of code you said is always false, is the component name Idle? some debugging should clear up whats going on

Comment: please post a complete code. Why type is `car` of? Are you sure all your conditions a met? did you try [debugging](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ManagedCodeDebugging.html) your code line by line?

Comment: FindWithTag does not work on inactive gameobjects.